# (Solved) Why is this set both open and closed

Tags: differential-geometry

In Serge Lang's Introduction to Differential Manifolds, it says (page 21),

> Furthermore, the set of points $x\in X$ for which there exists a chart $(U_i, \phi_i)$ at $x$ such that $E_i$ is linearly isomorphic to a given space $E$ is both open and closed.

Here $X$ is Hausdorff topological space, $E$ is a vector space, and $E_i$ is another vector space corresponding to the chart $(U_i, \phi_i)$.

Lang did not explain the reason so this may be obvious. But I cannot convince myself this is true. Also very few books introduces manifolds in the way Lang did, so I failed to find other references.

Any helps?

---

Update: see comments.

Comment: What is the meaning of "$E_i$ is another vector space corresponding to the chart $(U_i, \phi_i)$"? (Are you working on vector bundle and $E_i$ is somehow the local trivialization?)

Comment: Can you see that the set is open?

Comment: Lang defines the atlas as:  Each $\phi_i$ is a topological isomorphism of $U_i$ onto an open subset $\phi_i U_i$ of some vector space $E_i$ and for any $i, j$, $\phi_i (U_i \cap U_j)$ is open in $E_i$. So $E_i$ is some vector space that is given when we define the charts. @JohnMa

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. This set is the union (At first I mistook it to be the intersection :P) of all $\phi_i ^{-1} E_i$ with $i$ ranging over the the charts with specified properties. So they are necessarily open. But what about being closed?

Comment: The intersection would typically be empty. [That would make it open, but that's beside the point.] It's the union of some family of the $U_i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, yes. So the openness is guaranteed by that it is the union of open sets. The closeness is because its complement is also the union of open sets. Thank you for the hint.